# Apply Jquery Accordian to XML Tag

Tags: jquery, css, xml, xslt

I have an XML with the help of XSLT I created accordion applied style for the XML Code

Now I am trying to create Jquery Accordian.

Here Is my XML Code

```
<NavItem id="client1" ImageURL="/cs/PADEV/cache/AGL_NAV_COL_PERSON_21.GIF" Name="ADMN_F201312300957205437788018" SequenceNumber="3" Label="My Information"  TargetPortal="EMPLOYEE" Type="Folder" isVirtual="False">
<NavItem Label="Personal Information" Name="ADMN_S201312300957415580614642" SequenceNumber="4" isNewWindow="False" isTopWindow="True"/>
<NavItem Label="Mailing Address" Name="ADMN_S201312300957415580614642" SequenceNumber="4" isNewWindow="False" isTopWindow="True"/>
</NavItem>

<NavItem id="client2" ImageURL="/cs/PADEV/cache/AGL_NAV_COL_PERSON_21.GIF" Name="ADMN_F201312300957205437788018" SequenceNumber="3" Label="My Contact"  TargetPortal="EMPLOYEE" Type="Folder" isVirtual="False">
<NavItem Label="Phone" Name="ADMN_S201312300957415580614642" SequenceNumber="4" isNewWindow="False" isTopWindow="True"/>
<NavItem Label="Email" Name="ADMN_S201312300957415580614642" SequenceNumber="4" isNewWindow="False" isTopWindow="True"/>
</NavItem>
```

And here is my XSLT code

```
<div id="accordian">
<xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 0">
    <h3 title="{@Description}" id="check1">
        <!--<img src="{$imgSrc}" />-->
        <xsl:value-of select="@Label"/>
    </h3>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 1">
    <h3 title="{@Description}" id = "check2" >
        <!--<img src="{$imgSrc}" />-->
        <a href="#" style="color:white;text-decoration:none;"><xsl:value-of select="@Label"/></a>
    </h3>
</xsl:if>

</div>
<div id="test1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./NavItem[@Type='Folder' and @SequenceNumber]"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./NavItem[@Type='Shortcut']"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="./NavItem[@Type='Folder' and not(@SequenceNumber)]"/>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
 #<xsl:value-of select="$selector"/> h3,  #<xsl:value-of select="$selector"/> 
       {

        width:200px;
        font-family:calibri;
        white-space:nowrap;
        background-color:#f2f2f2;
        font-size:15px;         
        padding:5px;
        margin:3px;
        text-decoration:none;

       }
      #<xsl:value-of select="$selector"/> div a {
        display: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        width:270px;
        padding:5px;
        margin:3px;
        font-family:calibri;
        color:white;
        white-space:nowrap;
        background-color:#f2f2f2;
        font-size:15px;
        letter-spacing:1px;

      }
      #<xsl:value-of select="$selector"/> div a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color:#d2d2d2;
      }
    #check1
    {
        background:url('blue_1.png') repeat-x center; 
        font-family:Calibri !important;
        font-size:14px !important;
        color:white;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        padding:5px;
        height:22px;            
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #check2
    {
        background:url('pink_2.png') repeat-x center; 
        font-family:Calibri !important;
        font-size:14px !important;
        color:white;
        letter-spacing:2px;
        padding:5px;
        height:22px;            
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

Kindly Help me how to apply Jquery Accordian.

1)  My Information
2) My Contact

When user click the first My Information

In the sub accordion menu these are the values 
Personal Information & Mailing Address

When user click the Second Accordion Menu My Contact
In the sub accordion menu these are the values 
Phone & Email.

Sorry for the Long Question.

Kindly help me how to apply Jquery accordian to the above code

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ ?

Change XSL code to:

```
<div id="accordion">
<xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 0">
    <h3 title="{@Description}" id="check5">
        <!--<img src="{$imgSrc}" />-->
        <xsl:value-of select="@Label"/>
    </h3>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="position() mod 5 = 1">
    <h3 title="{@Description}" id = "check1" >
        <!--<img src="{$imgSrc}" />-->
        <a href="#" style="color:white;text-decoration:none;"><xsl:value-of select="@Label"/></a>
    </h3>
</xsl:if>
</div>
```

Add the following to the header:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi I have tried the above code

all of us sudden my first he tag is disappeared and I am getting an error

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'accordion'

I even put CDN for Jquery

Comment: Hi I have added jquery ui .js now I am not getting any error but still 

My first h3 tag is disappeared Kindly help to solve this

Comment: can you paste the source code? im in doubt of how your h3 disappear. does the entire code disappear?